# Should user auto-login after registration?

Tags: authentication, registration, autologin

Is it safe to login user automatically after registration?

User fills registration form, some info message is sent to his mailbox, and what then:

- User redirected to login page asking him for credentials;

**OR**

- User auto-logins as his newly created user?

I feel something not safe enough in auto-login, but can't figure it out!

Comment: I'm curious if there's a real security reason behind it, because I personally find it terribly annoying when I register and I'm not automatically logged in.

Comment: from a user stand point that is very annoying to log-in again

Comment: It is annoying yes, but security and convenience are often a trade-off.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If they just filled out the login information and you're not concerned about confirming that the email address is legit, then there shouldn't be a problem just logging them in directly.

However, you open yourself up to people/bots creating bogus accounts (at least ones without legitimate email addresses). If you're concerned about that (not sure it this is a public facing app or intranet, etc) then you should at least verify the email address by sending a link with a guid or some identifier that you can track back. Then you can let them log-in once they are confirmed.

You could also just tie it to their StackExchange/Facebook/OpenID/etc account and not make users fill out yet another form and worry about maintaining all that information.

Answer (score 5):

They should need to login. Also the confirmation email should *not* contain their password. If they managed to give you the wrong email address and you automatically log them in then someone else has access to their account now. This holds even if you have them type their email address twice. Sometimes people make the same mistake twice in a row.

Comment: *"If they managed to give you the wrong email address and you automatically log them in then someone else has access to their account now."* - That statement doesn't really make sense in the context of the question.  Barring any concerns about sending sensitive information in an email (which wasn't in the question), auto-logging-in the user who just registered gives access to the user who just registered.  How can somebody else intercept that?

Comment: I just assumed it was understood that the account needs to be confirmed by clicking a link in the confirmation email. Skipping this step is an even bigger security flaw than automatically logging someone in after confirmation. The real question isn't whether the user should be logged in immediately after filling out the registration form. It's whether they should be logged in after clicking the confirmation link in the email.

Comment: @akronymn actually the real question was "Should user auto-login after registration?"

Comment: @jay yeah and? I answered that question and used the issues with account validation to explain why.

Answer (score 3):

It can be safe to auto login if the user already has an active session as the correct user during the confirmation step. If you think about it, it's not actually "automatically logging them in" but simply keeping them logged in as they was before.

1. User registers
2. Keep a session identifying the user
3. User navigates to the confirmation page (linked in email)
4. You activate the account

During all that time, there was no reason to end the session. The only reason you would want to end the session (or not create one in the first place) is if your permissions are not properly set to allow someone to login / create a session without giving them higher privileges than an unregistered user.

Now, be sure not to automatically identify the user as X simply because this person navigated to the confirmation page of user X. If a user navigates to this page but does not already have a session open, do not assume he knows the password.